# Highcharts datagrouping in rangeSelector and Series at the same time?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Guys is it possible to use dataGrouping in both places - inside rangeSelector and and in series?
What I'm trying to achieve:

1. to have fixed grouping of data depending on zoom level (like always one hour aggregation for 1M)
2. for some properties I need default 'average' approximation rule, but for some ones - 'sum'. That's why I add this on serie level.

   `rangeSelector: {
               enabled: true,
               selected: 1,
               buttons: [
                   {
                       type: "week",
                       count: 1,
                       text: "1W",
                       dataGrouping: {
                           forced: true,
                           units: [["minute", [1]]]
                       }
                   },
                   {
                       type: "month",
                       count: 1,
                       text: "1M",
                       dataGrouping: {
                           forced: true,
                           units: [["hour", [1]]],
                       }
                   }
             ]
      }
   ...
      let serie = {
          data,
          name: 'some property',
          dataGrouping: {approximation: "sum"}
      }`

Comment: Type of the approximation should be set in the button options, otherwise you will always see `sum` approximation. Regarding fixed grouping, I would use custom callback (see [rangeSelector.buttons.events.click](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector.buttons.events.click)) and call there `series.update({ dataGrouping: { ... });` to set only one, available dataGrouping for the series. In general, you can use this callback to update series with options you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot! For some reason button.events.click handler didn't invoke, but I was able to apply `series.update` in `afterSetExtremes` handler which even better for me, because in that case I can also apply aggregation if user uses zoom or rangeSelectorInput. 
I didn't see update method for series in api docs, seem it missing there.

Comment: `Series.update()` can be found here: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update :)

Comment: I see, thanks, I've been looking here https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.
Actually with updating series every time I faced performance issues. Have very large data amount. But at least it works!

Comment: You can improve performance by disabling animation and [`scrollbar.liveRedraw`](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/scrollbar.liveRedraw) if your scrollbar is enabled.